# Improve order complexity of getting alphabet order from sorted strings

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

Say I have a list(of size n) of lexicographically sorted strings(max size m) in some language consisting of `a-z` but not the vocabulary order of `a, b, c...`. Now the main question is that I want to find the order of the alphabet. So I divide the problem into two parts:

1. Find ordered pairs of alphabets from the strings in the list.
2. Construct  a directed graph from these pairs as edges. Do a topological sort on the graph to get the order.

My question is regarding the first.

To do 1., I did an O(n^2m) loop:

```
vector<pair<char, char> > build_ordered_pairs(vector<string> words) {
    vector<pair<char, char> > ordered_pairs;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
            k = 0;
            while(k < words[i].size() && k < words[j].size() && words[i][k] == words[j][k])
                k++;
            if(k < words[i].size() && k < words[j].size())
                ordered_pairs.push_back(make_pair(words[i][k], words[j][k]));
        }
    }
    return ordered_pairs;
}
```

To improve this we can put the strings in trie and then get the pairs from each level of the trie. But this would again be quadratic in n. Can we do better, say nlogn or maybe n?

We may be getting the same pairs again and again. So can we make a check that a certain pair is not required and thus we can skip it while building the directed graph simultaneously. Thanks in advance.

Sample input-output pair :

```
words = {"baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad"}
required = {'b', 'd', 'a', 'c'}
```

P.S : Tagging as python also, as solutions/suggestions in both work for me.

Comment: @blhsing, edited with sample input-output pair. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're examining way more pairs of strings than you need to. You only need to examine consecutive pairs of strings, not all pairs. The information you get by comparing strings 0 and 3 is implied by the 0-1, 1-2, and 2-3 comparisons, and the topological sort can handle it for you. The topological sort should run *faster* with less extraneous edges in the input, too.

Answer (score 1):

Been working on the actual implementation but @user2357112 already explained the gist of it. Since the list is already lexicographically sorted, you can simply keep track of the first letter of the last word while you iterate through the list, and if it's the same as the first letter of the current word, put the rest of the current word into a list until the first letter of the current word is different from that of the last word, at which point pass on the list for a recursive call. The average time complexity of this implementation would be O(n*log(n)) instead.

Here's an implementation in Python (using `collections.deque` for efficient `popleft` operation):

```
from collections import deque
def build_ordered_pairs(words):
    output = []
    if len(words) < 2:
        return output
    last_letter = None
    same_prefix = deque()
    while words:
        letter, *rest = words.popleft()
        if letter == last_letter:
            same_prefix.append(rest)
        else:
            if last_letter:
                output.append((last_letter, letter))
            output.extend(build_ordered_pairs(same_prefix))
            same_prefix = deque([rest])
        last_letter = letter
    output.extend(build_ordered_pairs(same_prefix))
    return output
```

so that:

```
words = deque(["baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad"])
print(build_ordered_pairs(words))
```

would output:

```
[('b', 'a'), ('a', 'c'), ('d', 'a'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Since you already know about topological sort I won't elaborate on the rest of the implementation.